# iTunes home sharing videos with iOS 10.2 TV app

Tags: itunes, ios, home-sharing, tv.app

I have videos in iTunes on my Mac desktop (in the `TV Shows` and `Movies` sections) that are shared using Home Sharing with my Apple ID. Home sharing is turned on and working; I can watch the videos on my Apple TV.

I used to use Apple's `Videos` app to watch on my iPhone. As of iOS 10.2, `Videos` seems to be gone, nominally replaced with `TV`. Apple's [instructions for Home Sharing](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202190), published Dec 6, 2016, refer to `Videos` and don't mention `TV` at all.

I don't see any obvious way to watch shared videos with the `TV` app. I went to its `Settings` pane and signed out of my Apple ID and back in, but still nothing. The `Settings` pane *does* explicitly list `Home Sharing`, which suggests that it should be possible, but I am stumped.

How can I watch videos shared from `iTunes` using `Home Sharing` on my iPhone with iOS 10.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that once i downloaded a free tv episode my shared library showed up. [image]

Comment: Worked for me! Except when I tap the name of my shared library, I get a blank page with a spinning progress indicator that never ends.

Comment: I don't know why this was down-voted. Indeed, I had my "Home Sharing" library missing from the TV app and it started showing up after I "purchased" a free episode of some show.

Answer (score 1):

The TV app will show all iTunes libraries that are shared under the same Home Sharing account right on the "front page"

When you start the app, you should be on the "Library" tab (check tab at bottom, you have "Library", "Watch Now", "Store" and "Search").

Your home sharing libraries will be listed on the Library page, you have  "TV Shows", "Movies" and then the name of your library, with the name you picked in iTunes' General Preferences, Library Name. If you have more than one iTunes instance running on your network, and they're all shared on the same account, they will all show up there.

Comment: [Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Vm6F.png) what I see on the `Library` tab when I start the app. I haven't purchased or rented any videos, so that is OK, but there's nothing about home sharing at all.

Comment: And [here](http://imgur.com/a/dsM0l) is mine, showing "Peter's Library" from home sharing. Makes me wonder if they have a bug that doesn't show home sharing if there's no content for the other items.

Answer (score 1):

I have multiple devices for the family with multiple accounts, all of which share the same Home Sharing account. It used to work, and does on my personal device, but not the rest of the family sharing the same home sharing account. Use a different iCloud ID and login with your home sharing account and you'll see.

Comment: In the same situation.  We started purchasing TV shows, movies, and music from iTunes when iTunes first made them available over a decade ago I'd guess.  We've thousands of dollars of shows and movies that our children love to watch again and again, stored on our NAS.  With recent changes, introduction of the TV app, none of these are listed anymore and even restoring past purchases on other devices via child accounts is ridiculous difficult.  It's coercive with the intent on making consumers accidentally purchase again or switch to their new, expensive subscribe-per-show business model.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no purchased/rented content, it will not show up.  As soon as you load some kind of content it will show up on the Library page.  If this is intentional, it stinks...